# Question on how MATLAB's pdepe solver works

Tags: pde, matlab, numerics, numerical-modelling, pdepe

I'm solving the following 1D transport equation in MATLAB's pdepe solver.

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} =  D\frac{\partial ^2 C}{\partial x^2}-v\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$$

At the inlet (left boundary), Dirichlet boundary condition is applied $C(1) = C_L$ . (1 is the inlet node number)

At the outlet (right boundary), diffusive flux is ignored. $-D \frac{dC}{dx} = 0$

Implementation of the above boundary conditions in MATLAB's [pdepe](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) solver.

```
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = bcfun(xl,cl,xr,cr,t)
    pl = cl - 3;
    ql = 0;
    pr = 0;
    qr = 1;
end
```

From what I understand, the spatial direction is discretized and the resulting ode's are solved using `ode15s` in `pdepe` solver.

I'd tried to do the same in my own version of code that implements whats is done in `pdepe` solver. However, my results don't agree with the `pdepe` solver. I've used the backward difference scheme for the first derivative and centered difference scheme for the second derivative.I'm not sure about the scheme implemented in MATLAB's pdepe solver.

I've implemented the boundary conditions in the following way.

```
dC(1) = 0
dC(nnode,1) = -v*(C(nnode) - C(nnode-1))/delx + (D/delx^2)*2*(C(nnode-1) - C(nnode))
```

Right boundary condition: $-D \frac{dC}{dx} = 0$
$$ \frac{C_{N+1} - C_{N-1}}{2 \Delta x} = 0$$

At last node,

```
dC(nnode,1) = -v*(C(nnode) - C(nnode-1))/delx + (D/delx^2)*(C(nnode-1) - C(nnode) +C(nnode+1))
```

is equal to

```
dC(nnode,1) = -v*(C(nnode) - C(nnode-1))/delx + (D/delx^2)*2*(C(nnode-1) - C(nnode))
```

The complete code is

```
function sol=so()
format short
global D nnode init_co find_index v
m = 0;
delx = 0.25;
xend = 10; 
D = 500;
v = 200;
x = 0:delx:xend;
find_index  = x;
tspan = 0:0.00001:1;
init_co = [3 ; zeros(length(x)-1,1)];
nnode = length(x);

%% pdepe solver
sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,x,tspan)
figure(1)
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(tspan,sol)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('c')
xlim([-0.01 0.5])
ylim([2.995 3.005])
title('MATLAB - pdepe')
grid on


function [g,f,s] = pdefun(x,t,c,DcDx)
g = 1;
f = D*DcDx;
s = -v*DcDx;
end

function c0 = icfun(x)
c0 = init_co(find(find_index==x));
end

function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = bcfun(xl,cl,xr,cr,t)
    pl = cl - 3;
    ql = 0;
    pr = 0;
    qr = 1;
end

function dC= mysolver(t,C)
    dC(1,1) = 0;
    for i = 2:nnode-1
        dC(i,1) = -v*(C(i) - C(i-1))/delx + D/delx^2*(C(i-1) -2*C(i) + C(i+1)); 
    end
    dC(nnode,1) = -v*(C(nnode) - C(nnode-1))/delx + (D/delx^2)*2*(C(nnode-1) - C(nnode)); % DdC/dx = 0
end

%% my solver
[tspan C]  = ode15s(@(t,s) mysolver(t,s), tspan , init_co);
figure(1)
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(tspan,C)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('c')
xlim([-0.01 0.5])
ylim([2.995 3.005])
title('My solver')
grid on


% figure(2)
% plot(tspan, abs(sol - C))
% title('Absolute error')
end
```

The resulting absolute error( pdepe solution - my implementation) is

[image]
Also, the absolute error increases with an increase in mesh size (increasing `delx` from 0.25 to 1).

[image]
I am not sure why the absolute error increases. Is it because of the backward and centered difference schemes that I 've used or is it due to the way in which my boundary condition has been implemented?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put axes on your plots and maybe explain a bit more? Your numerical problem is definined on $[0,10]$ but your PDE has a left inflow condition at $x=1$? Also, you are taking $\Delta x$ quite large. Taking it smaller and smaller and still seeing nondecreasing error is a good indication that your spatial scheme is messed up somewhere, and the $x$ location where the errors are high might also tell you if one of the boundary conditions is messed up

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks a lot for the response. When you say ,`"but your PDE has a left inflow condition at x=1?"` do you mean there is a mistake in this line dC(1,1) = 0? I set dC(1,1)=0 since MATLAB indexing starts from 1. Please let me know if you are point to any other line in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between `pdepe` and your finite difference code is that `pdepe`
basically uses a central difference approximation consistently where your
code uses a combination of backward and central difference approximations.

When I run my modified code, shown below, with your original spatial discretization,
the maximum difference between the `pdepe` solution and finite difference is on the
order of 1e-13.

You'll notice I made a few other changes to your code. One of these was to reduce the
time span of the solution; very little happens to the solution after about .1 seconds.
Also, I changed the way the Dirichlet constraint is applied at the left end. You used
a "rate form" to specify this constraint. Theoretically that is fine but numerically
it introduces a slight error in the solution; this is known as "constraint drift."
I prescribed this constraint using an algebraic equation; this is also how `pdepe` applies this type of constraint.
If you run my code with the rate form of the constraint by setting `useRateFormDirichlet=true`,
the maximum difference is 1e-10; so the effect of this change is small.

```
function cse_02_09_20
m = 0;
delx = 0.25;
xend = 10; 
D = 500;
v = 200;
x = 0:delx:xend;
find_index  = x;
tf=.1;
tspan=linspace(0,tf,100);
init_co = [3 ; zeros(length(x)-1,1)];
nnode = length(x);
fdRHS = @(t,x) mysolver(t,x,v,D,delx);
useRateFormDirichlet=false;
fdRHS = @(t,x) cdRHS(t,x,v,D,delx,useRateFormDirichlet);
% make ode solver tolerances very small so we can
% better see effects of spatial discretoization differences
opts=odeset('abstol', 1e-10, 'reltol', 1e-9);
%% pdepe solver
sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,x,tspan,opts);

  function [g,f,s] = pdefun(x,t,c,DcDx)
    nx=length(x);
    g = ones(1,nx); 
    f = D*DcDx;
    s = -v*DcDx;
  end

  function c0 = icfun(x)
    c0 = init_co(find(find_index==x));
  end

  function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = bcfun(xl,cl,xr,cr,t)
    pl = cl - 3;
    ql = 0;
    pr = 0;
    qr = 1;
  end

%% finite difference solver
e = ones(nnode,1);
jpat = spdiags([e e e],-1:1,nnode,nnode);
% improve performance by specifying a pattern for the jacobian
opts=odeset(opts, 'jpattern', jpat);
if ~useRateFormDirichlet
  opts=odeset(opts, 'mass', spdiags([0; ones(nnode-1,1)], 0, nnode, nnode));
end
tic
[tspan, C]  = ode15s(fdRHS, tspan , init_co, opts);
toc

solutionDifference=abs(sol-C);

figure; plot(tspan, sol(:,end), tspan, C(:,end)); grid;
title 'end C as a function of time'
legend('pdepe', 'finite difference');

figure; plot(x, sol(end,:), x, C(end,:)); grid;
title 'C at final time';
legend('pdepe', 'finite difference');

figure; plot(tspan, solutionDifference(:,end)); grid;
title 'tip difference as a function of time'

maxSolDiff=max(solutionDifference(:));
fprintf('Maximum difference between pdepe and finite difference=%g\n', ...
  maxSolDiff);

end

function dC= mysolver(t,C,v,D,delx)
N=size(C,1);
dC=zeros(N,1);
i = 2:N-1;
dC(i) = -v*(C(i) - C(i-1))/delx + D/delx^2*(C(i-1) -2*C(i) + C(i+1));
dC(N) = -v*(C(N) - C(N-1))/delx + (D/delx^2)*2*(C(N-1) - C(N)); % DdC/dx = 0
end

function dC=cdRHS(t,C,v,D,delx,useRateFormDirichlet)
N=size(C,1);
dC=zeros(N,1);
if ~useRateFormDirichlet
  dC(1)=C(1)-3;
end
i = 2:N-1;
dC(i) = -v*(C(i+1) - C(i-1))/(2*delx) + D/delx^2*(C(i-1) -2*C(i) + C(i+1));
dC(N) = -v*(C(N) - C(N-1))/delx + 2*D/delx^2*(C(N-1) - C(N)); % DdC/dx = 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed solution. From what I understand, the truncation error of the backward difference is O( $\Delta x$) and that of centered difference is O($\Delta x^2$). The errors obtained from the numerical scheme is of the order 0.04 for backward + central difference and  1e-13  for central alone.  I am not able to clearly understand what leads to this drastic difference. Could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: That is really a separate question about the accuracy of these different numerical schemes and is covered in detail in many texts. Your mesh in the spatial direction is quite coarse. If you use one or two orders of magnitude more points, you can also get solutions with the two schemes that are close to each other. But your question basically was "How does pdepe work?" and that is what I answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I've created a new post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34414/question-on-comparing-the-accuracy-of-numerical-schemes)